# DatePicker is always set to the first row ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

My datepicker is always set to the first row. Will it be implemented dynamically or I have some issues with my system?

```
  <tbody class="TrimGridContent" id="trimBody">
                        @foreach (TrimsAccessoriesOrderModel trimsData in TrimsData)
                        {
                            <tr class="TrimGridFields">
                                <td >
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="singleTrimGridCheck" value="@trimsData.GridTranId">
                                </td>
                                <td>@trimsData.SerialNumber</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridOrderDate</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridSyleNo</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridItemName</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridItemCode</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridStoreName</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridSupplierName</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridOrderQty</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridUnitName</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridUnitPrice</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridDeliveryDate</td>
                                <td>@trimsData.GridRemarks</td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SupplierDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Supplier Date", @id = "SupplierDate"})
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RevisedDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Revised Date", @id = "RevisedDate"})
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InHouseDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "In House Date", @id = "InHouseDate"})
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
```

If I give input to the second or third row except for the first datepicker row, the date is set to the first row which is named as Supplier Date.

[image]

This is my js.

```js
@section Scripts {
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   <script>
       $('.datepicker').datepicker({
           changeMonth: true,
           changeYear: true,
           dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
       });
     </script>
       }
```

Have anyone faced this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your problem occurred because you're putting `@Html.TextBoxFor()` helpers inside foreach loop with predefined `@id = "SupplierDate"` parameter, which rendered all corresponding textboxes with same `id` attribute instead of unique ID names. Hence, you should try using `for` loop and `TrimsData` collection index while removing `id` attribute definition (let the helper creates unique `id` attribute values):

```
@for (int i = 0; i < TrimsData.Count; i++)
{
    <tr class="TrimGridFields">
        <td>
           <input type="checkbox" class="singleTrimGridCheck" value="@TrimsData[i].GridTranId">
        </td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].SerialNumber</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridOrderDate</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridSyleNo</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridItemName</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridItemCode</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridStoreName</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridSupplierName</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridOrderQty</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridUnitName</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridUnitPrice</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridDeliveryDate</td>
        <td>@TrimsData[i].GridRemarks</td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrimsData[i].SupplierDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Supplier Date" })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrimsData[i].RevisedDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Revised Date" })
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TrimsData[i].InHouseDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "In House Date" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Or if you have another `TrimsData` property which has unique value, set the textbox ID values with that property like example below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SupplierDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Supplier Date", @id = trimsData.Id })
```

Related issue:

[JQuery Datepicker for multiple .NET MVC Input Fields not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112787/jquery-datepicker-for-multiple-net-mvc-input-fields-not-working)

Comment: Good answer for the issue :)

Comment: @Tetsuya It worked for only SupplierDate column, but when I again give input to Revised date, the date is changed to the corresponding SupplierDate column! Here is the code   `<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SupplierDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Supplier Date", @id = trimsData.GridTranId }) </td>
<td> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RevisedDate, new {@class = "form-control datepicker", @placeholder = "Revised Date", @id = trimsData.GridTranId })
</td>`

Answer (score 0):

one reason i think is that the datepicker run after the dynamic textboxes are rendered. you have to re trigger again the datepicker initialization for it to work.